# How to identify boundaries of a binary image to crop in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How to identify boundaries of a binary image to crop in matlab?
ie. the input binary image has no noises. only has one black object in white background.

Comment: Any attempted codes ?

Comment: see this ones as a hint... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619416/building-an-outer-bounding-box-from-multiple-smaller-boxes/23625641#23625641

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `edge` command in MATLAB.

```
E = edge(I);
```

`I` would be an input grayscale or binary image.  This will return a binary image with only the edges.

This can provide further assistance:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html

Comment: The only benefit I can see in using edge detection is that it reduces the amount of pixels to search for when finding the minimum spanning bounding box.  The core algorithm itself when finding the bounding box is what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is just black-and-white and has a single object, you can likely make use of the [Flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm, for which Matlab has built-in support!

Try the `imfill` function ([ref](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html)).

This should give you the extents of the object, which would allow you to crop at will.

Comment: My input image has a filled image. Suppose, there is a black filled circle in the white background. I want to find the boundaries of the minimum square which can include the circle.

Comment: Good idea with flood fill, but it is overkill to find the boundaries of a simple object.

Answer (score 0):

You can also invert the image, then do `regionprops` to extract all of the properties for separate objects.  You need to invert the image as `regionprops` assumes that the objects are **white** while the background is black.  A good thing about this approach is that it generalizes for multiple objects and you only need about a few lines of code to do it.

As an example, let's artificially create a circle in the centre of an image that is black on a white background as you have suggested.  Let's assume this is also a binary image.

```
im = true(200, 200);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:200, 1:200);
ind = (X-100).^2 + (Y-100).^2 <= 1000;
im(ind) = false;
imshow(im);
```

This is what your circle will look like:

[image]

Now let's go ahead and invert this so that it's a white circle on black background:

```
imInvert = ~im;
imshow(imInvert);
```

This is what your inverted circle will look like:

[image]

Now, invoke `regionprops` to find properties of all of the objects in our image.  In this case, there should only be one.

```
s = regionProps(imInvert, 'BoundingBox');
```

As such, `s` contains a structure that is 1 element long, and has a single field called `BoundingBox`.  This field is a 4 element array that is structured in the following way:

```
[x y w h]
```

`x` denotes the column/vertical co-ordinate while `y` denotes the row/horizontal co-ordinate of the **top-left corner** of the bounding box.  `w,h` are the width and height of the rectangle.  Our output of the above code is:

```
s = 

BoundingBox: [68.5000 68.5000 63 63]
```

This means that the top-left corner of our bounding box is located at `(x,y) = (68.5,68.5)`, and has a width and height of 63 each.  Therefore, the span of our bounding box goes from rows `(68.5,131.5)` and columns `(68.5,131.5)`.  To make sure that we have the right bounding box, you can draw a rectangle around our shape by using the rectangle command.

```
imshow(im);
rectangle('Position', s.BoundingBox);
```

This is what your image will look like with a rectangle drawn around the object.  As you can see, the bounding box given from `regionprops` is the minimum spanning bounding box required to fully encapsulate the object.

[image]

If you wish to crop the object, you can do the following:

```
 imCrop = imcrop(imInvert, s.BoundingBox);
```

This should give you the cropped image that is defined by the bounding box that we talked about earlier.

Hope this is what you're looking for.  Good luck!

Comment: I used as you said this code.


It only genarates the original n inverted images. No cropping. Can you explain why?

Comment: im = imread('22.JPG'); 

subplot(3,3,1);

imshow(im);

title('Original');


imInvert = ~im;

subplot(3,3,2);
imshow(imInvert);

s = regionprops(imInvert, 'BoundingBox');
subplot(3,3,3);
imshow(s);

a = rectangle('Position', s.BoundingBox);
subplot(3,3,4);
imshow(a);

b = imcrop(im,s);
subplot(3,3,5);
imshow(b);

Comment: @user2234446 You aren't calling `imcrop` properly.  You need to do `b = imcrop(im,s.BoundingBox);`.  The second parameter accepts an array of 4 numbers.  You are passing in the **structure** that contains the information, not the array itself.  I have also edited my post for you to see the correct syntax.  Good luck.

Comment: **ALSO:** Make sure that the image is **black and white**.  It could be an RGB image, even though it only has two kinds of intensities.  Do `im = im2bw(im);` after you read in your image before your proceed.

Comment: **ALSO #2**:  Doing `imshow(s)` is utter nonsense.  It is a structure containing data that is not related to image pixel data.  As such, you need to get rid of that call.  Also, you need to call `rectangle` after you do `imshow(im);`

Comment: @user2234446 Do you require any further assistance?  If not, please consider accepting one of our answers