# MATLAB Boundingbox around object detected with Eigen Value Algorithm

Tags: matlab, bounding-box, object-detection

I have an image of an object that I want to crop using the Eigen Value Algorithm, everything is fine until I want to draw a Bounding Box around the detected features to use as the area of significance.

```
original = imread('1.jpg');
img = rgb2gray(original);

corners = detectMinEigenFeatures(img);
figure;
imshow(original); hold on;
plot(corners.selectStrongest(4000));

%st = regionprops( corners.selectStrongest(4000), 'BoundingBox' ); 

%rect = st.BoundingBox; 

crop = imcrop(original,rect);
figure
imshow(crop);
```

[image: ObjectDetected]

My problem is that the variable corners is (n x 1) and I don't know how that relates to coordinates in my original image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your output `corner` is an object for storing corner points, use `corner.Location` to get an  M-by-2 array of [x y] point coordinate.

Comment: I'm getting close, any idea how I can get to a perfect crop?

Comment: how do you define a "perfect crop"? why using this method and not just threshold and\or edge of the image? it's pretty noise free.

Comment: I found that using edge(img,'canny',0.1); works the best but stuck on getting the boundingbox again, please help.

Comment: see this for a hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619416/building-an-outer-bounding-box-from-multiple-smaller-boxes/23625641#23625641